# No application encryption key has been specified but it has been

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

i keep getting the following error.

```
[2022-03-09 08:30:49] production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Encryption\\MissingAppKeyException(code: 0): No application encryption key has been specified. at /Users/XXX/Documents/GijsCode/mfg/dashboard-mfg/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php:101)
[stacktrace]
```

This is weird because on my ubuntu pc where i mainly develop i didnt get this error. Now iam working on a mac and i cant seem to get rid of the error.

i have tried clearing the cache and generating it again but the error occurs when running the command php artisan key:generate

Error message when running php artisan key:generate

```
/.env): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/KeyGenerateCommand.php:96
     92▕     {
     93▕         file_put_contents($this->laravel->environmentFilePath(), preg_replace(
     94▕             $this->keyReplacementPattern(),
     95▕             'APP_KEY='.$key,
  ➜  96▕             file_get_contents($this->laravel->environmentFilePath())
     97▕         ));
     98▕     }
     99▕ 
    100▕     /**

      +16 vendor frames 
  17  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

I hope anyone knows the answer to this bug because I'am absolutely clueless.

EDIT:

I fixed it by hardcoding the path into the config file.

Comment: As we keep saying here again and again, the generic 500 Internal Server Error message reported back to the frontend, does not contain any information about the actual _cause_ of the error (deliberately so) - and that to find out more details, you need to go check the error log on the server ...

Comment: Sorry, updated it. fairly new to web development. Could you maybe take a second look at it? would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How are `vue.js` or `axios` related to this problem?

Comment: Because the error got thrown by trying to login where it used to work before

Comment: it simply looks / sounds like you forgot to create a .env file (typically copied from .env.example) - only then you can run `php artisan key:generate`